# Batch: ( unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I am getting this error

```
( was unexpected at this time
```

This is what i have

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "File=testdoc.txt"
set "Temp=%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"

set "TaskNumber=%~1" 

findstr /B /L /M /C:"%TaskNumber%:" "%File%" >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 echo ERROR: %TaskNumber% not found in file "%File%" & goto:eof 

set var="false"
if /I "%~2" == "enable" set var="true"
if "%~2" == "" set var="true"

if "!var!" == "true" (
del "%Temp%" 2>nul
for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ("%File%") do (
     if not "%%I" == "%TaskNumber%" (
        echo %%I:%%J>>"%Temp%"
    ) else (
          set "TextLine=%%I:%%J"    
            if not "%TextLine:~-2%" == ":N" (
                set "TextLine=%TextLine%:N"
                echo %TextLine%>>"%Temp%"
                )
            )

    )   
)


else (
if /I "%~2" == "disable" (
del "%Temp%" 2>nul
for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ("%File%") do (
    if not "%%I" == "%TaskNumber%" (
        echo %%I:%%J>>"%Temp%"
    ) else (
         set "TextLine=%%I:%%J" 
         if "%TextLine:~-2%" == ":N" (
                set "TextLine=%TextLine:~0,-2%"
                echo %TextLine%>>"%Temp%"
                )
            )

    )  
)
)

move /Y "%TempFile%" "%TextFile%" 2>nul
```

I researched a little about this and in most posts it said,using delayedExpansion would help but it doesnt seem to help either.. Any idea as to what could I be missing

Comment: have you passed any command line arguments to the script?

Comment: Your `else` should be on the same line as your previous closing parenthesis and separated by a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as the `else` issue you also had a delayed expansion problem and were resetting the `TextLine` variable unnecessarily.

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "File=testdoc.txt"
set "_Temp=%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"

set "TaskNumber=%~1"

findstr /B /L /M /C:"%TaskNumber%:" "%File%" >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 echo ERROR: %TaskNumber% not found in file "%File%" & goto:eof

set "var=false"
if /I "%~2" == "enable" set "var=true"
if "%~2" == "" set "var=true"

if "%var%" == "true" (
    del "%_Temp%" 2>nul
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ("%File%") do (
        if not "%%I" == "%TaskNumber%" (
            >>"%_Temp%" echo %%I:%%J
        ) else (
            set "TextLine=%%I:%%J"
            if not "!TextLine:~-2!" == ":N" (
                >>"%_Temp%" echo !TextLine!:N
            )
        )
    )
) else (
    if /I "%~2" == "disable" (
        del "%_Temp%" 2>nul
        for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ("%File%") do (
            if not "%%I" == "%TaskNumber%" (
                >>"%_Temp%" echo %%I:%%J
            ) else (
                set "TextLine=%%I:%%J"
                if "!TextLine:~-2!" == ":N" (
                    >>"%_Temp%" echo !TextLine:~0,-2!
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

move /Y "%TempFile%" "%TextFile%" 2>nul
```